# Split configuration into multiple files

Tags: init-file, osx, emacs24

It's a very simple task, really. But all my google results come up with complex solutions. I must be blind or going about this wrong. Anyway...

Here's what I want:

I want to split up my emacs configuration in the following structure:

```
.emacs.d/
  init.el
  custom1/
  custom2/
```

I want `init.el` to be as minimal as possible, just something that says "load all `.el` files in `custom1/` and `custom2/`, recursively". Whenever I put a new file in any of those two directories I want it to automatically be loaded when emacs is started.

It seems simple and easy to me. But I fail at finding a simple solution.

Comment: It looks like there is a solution about half-way down the page on the wiki:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsModular  I Googled **recursive load el emacs**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer based on the comment from @lawlist:

The file `~/.emacs.d/load-directory.el`:

```
(defun load-directory (directory)
  "Load recursively all `.el' files in DIRECTORY."
  (dolist (element (directory-files-and-attributes directory nil nil nil))
    (let* ((path (car element))
           (fullpath (concat directory "/" path))
           (isdir (car (cdr element)))
           (ignore-dir (or (string= path ".") (string= path ".."))))
      (cond
       ((and (eq isdir t) (not ignore-dir))
        (load-directory fullpath))
       ((and (eq isdir nil) (string= (substring path -3) ".el"))
        (load (file-name-sans-extension fullpath)))))))
```

Then in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/load-directory")
(load-directory "~/.emacs.d/custom1")
(load-directory "~/.emacs.d/custom2")
```

Comment: I think `load-directory` could be simplified to `(require 'find-lisp) (mapcar (lambda (fn) (load (file-name-sans-extension fn))) (find-lisp-find-files directory "\\.el\\'"))`